# SyncFramework with sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Hai
 this is shanker
  when i am going to use already existed client side data base in synframework I am getting the following error

Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand' for table 'accounts'; the transaction was rolled back. Ensure that the command syntax is correct.

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

can you verify that the bulkinsert procedures and user define table type are in your database? the bulk operations in Sync fx is only supported in Sql 2008 and Azure.

Comment: thanks for replay. I am using sqlserever2008R2. with syncframework2.1. is there any problem with there compactability...

Comment: SQL 2008 R2 should be fine and compatible. try running SQL Profiler so you get an idea of what SQL Command reaches your server, then try running it yourself in Query Analyzer so you get the underlying error.